# Connection between Xcode and MonoDevelop broken?

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm a new user and yesterday had a basic master/detail app working correctly, using a table view with dynamic cells. But after a  bit of editing the link between the Xcode storyboard and MonoDevelop seems partially broken. I am making changes in the style of the table view cells (e.g. adding or removing accessories, changing the style from 'Basic' to 'Left Detail'), but none of these changes have any affect when I run the code. More importantly  when I run the app the cells are static, not dynamic content as shown in Xcode.
I have checked the content of the storyboard in XML format in MonoDevelop and that is changing as expected.
Not everything in the connection is broken, e.g. if I add a button to the navigation bar this is showing up correctly when I run the app.
Help please!

Comment: Does MonoDevelop's status bar saying that it is syncing changes back from Xcode? Did you save the storyboard in Xcode before switching back to MonoDevelop?

Comment: Yes and yes. I am even browsing through the XML souce file (in MonoDevelop) and confirm that changes are being shown there, e.g. if I change from Basic to RightDetail, there are then two <label> elements in the <subviews> element instead of only one.

Comment: I think the problem happened when I accidentally changed the number of prototype cells from 1 to 2, and then changed back to one, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @jstedfast : I even removed the table view completely (and checked to see the xml source had changed) but the table still showed when I run the simulator! What can be going on?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any idea what could be wrong. Could you submit a bug report to bugzilla.xamarin.com?

Comment: as noted below in my own answer, the problem turned out to be entirely in Xcode not in MonoDevelop. Still not sure what is wrong but it does seem fraught with problems deleting items from a storyboard when they already have outlets or actions associated.

Answer (score 0):

After more experimentation (and having to rebuild my storyboard from scratch) I believe I have found a bug in MonoDevelop. It's reproducible like this:

1. Take a simple working app (I used [the 'tasky' sample](http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/tutorials/Working_with_Tables_and_Cells/Part_5_-_Using_XCode,_Interface_Builder,_and_Storyboards)) and open the storyboard.
2. In Xcode, delete the table view cell from the Root View Controller Table View.
3. Think "oops, I didn't want to delete that" so *close Xcode without saving* (I used the red 'LED' button for this) - this appears to be a bug in Xcode not MonoDevelop, in that there isn't a prompt to ask if I want to save before closing.
4. Open the storybaord again from the MonoDevelop solution view - the table view cell *is still deleted* - surely it shouldn't be because Xcode wasn't saved.
5. Now try to add the cell again, exactly as it was before. Even though it looks perfectly correct in Xcode, with a correct segue and marked as a prototype cell, it will not work correctly when the code is run.
6. Furthermore, if you add some code so that a basic cell is returned by GetCell (because DequeueReusableCell won't return a cell now) the format of the cell in the detail view is just stuck - changing its style to 'Right Detail' etc has no effect in the app when it is run, although it looks perfectly OK in XCode.

Now, I know it's all too easy for new users to think they have found bugs in code when in fact it's just being misused in some way. So it would be good if someone else could check my findings before I report this to Apple and/or Xamarin. If I'm correct it's a serious bug because the only solution I have found, if you don't have source-code control of some kind, is to rebuild your storyboard from scratch.

Thanks

Comment: Just discovered that autosaving docs is now built in to Lion! But that doesn't explain the MonoDevelop behaviour

Comment: Further testing has shown that the issue seems to be all in Xcode  and not MonoDevelop. I just cannot recreate a working prootype cell once it has been deleted.